# Git, Как добавить ветку, в уже существующую локальную ветку?

Tags: git, github

На локальной машине работаю в ветке, к примеру  localbranch. В этой ветке я допиливал какую нибудь функцию. И вот! Готово! Теперь я хочу перейти в ветку develop, и смерджить её, но так как я добавил на локальную машину только ветку `localbranch` (`git clone --single-branch -b localBranch *url*`) и **теперь я хочу перейти в ветку develop**. **Но я клонировал только одну ветку** и при переходе git мне выдаст что такой венки нет **(оно и понятно, она же на удалённом репо лежит)**.

Что я делаю в таком случае. Удаляю проект клонирую develop, после делаю merge localBranch.

А, мне нужно что бы не пришлось не чего удалят. А, просто нужно дозалить ветку в уже существующий локальный репозиторий.

По сути `git clone --single-branch -b develop *url*` но в туже папку.

Пробовал грузить master ветку полагая, что с ней скачаються всё существующие ветки, но увы нет. **Должен же быть способ, добавить ветку не удаляя существующую?**

Comment: Сдаётся мне что вы хотите [либо](https://stackoverflow.com/q/520650/5752652) `git branch -u upstream/foo foo` [либо](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2765421/5752652) `git checkout -b <branch>`. Но меня очень сильно сбивает то, что одной рукой вы говорите, что у вас локально нет ветки которая есть на сервере (develop есть на сервере, но нет локально), то другой рукой в заголовок выносите "в уже существующую локально". Давайте вы разберётесь в себе, приведёте вопрос в порядок и не будете кричать болдом -- это мало помогает пониманию. Вы сами видите, что у вас одна часть вопроса противоречит другой?

Comment: @A K Спасибо! Тоже нужные вещи!!! Но не то!

Comment: Тогда наверное вам нужно более тщательно объяснять вопросы. Совет: вместо болда можно было бы приложить `git status` и `git branch -a` - уверяю, было бы намного более понятно.

Comment: @A K выделил ключевые моменты. А, `git status` и `git branch -a` на мой взгляд непонятно. Я же написал что та ветка которая нужна не на локальном репо, значит и в `git branch -a` её бы не было. Это бы, мне кажется всё запутало только. Да и ответ дал (reshu) ! Как раз то что нужно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала предположим, что все изменения сохранены commit'ом. Т.е. git status выдает что "nothing to commit, working tree clean".

Я в таких случаях делаю так:

```
git pull
```

после чего у меня появляется ветка origin/develop, далее

```
git checkout develop
```

В результате я перехожу в локальную ветку develop.

На случай очень уж старого git'а, который может не уметь переключаться на ветку из origin'а (а еще в каких-то версиях git pull скачивал только текущую ветку), то раньше я делал так:

```
git fetch origin develop
git checkout FETCH_HEAD -b develop
```

Comment: выдаёт -> `git checkout -b FETCH_HEAD master
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'FETCH_HEAD' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'master' which can not be resolved as commit?` а, `git fetch origin develop` срабатывает

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не там -b сперва поставил. Попробуйте исправленный вариант.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!! Работает!!! Именно то что мне и нужно было!!!

Answer (score 3):

проблемы ваши вызваны использованием (довольно редко применяемой на практике) опции `--single-branch` команды `clone`.

это приводит к тому, что локальное хранилище конфигурируется на получение из удалённого **только одной указанной ветки**.

чтобы в данной ситуации получить из удалённого хранилища (по умолчанию имеет имя `origin`) другую ветку (например, `develop`), можно воспользоваться такой, к примеру, командой (показан и пример вывода):

```
$ git fetch origin develop:develop
From url-хранилища
 * [new branch]      develop    -> develop
```

в результате создаётся локальная ветка `develop`, связанная («tracked») с одноимённой веткой в удалённом хранилище. можно на неё переключиться (командой *checkout*), и полноценно работать (выполнять *pull/merge/push* и т.д. и т.п.)

---

использованный синткасис для *refspec* (см. [`$ man git-fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))

```
$ git fetch хранилище ветка1:ветка2
```

означает в данном случае, что:

- из указанного хранилища будет получена `ветка1` (её локальное имя будет `хранилище/ветка1`
- будет создана (если отсутствовала) локальная `ветка2`
- `ветка2` будет [свазана («tracked»)](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8#r_tracking_branches) с `хранилище/ветка1`

Comment: Спасибо!  reshu уже дал ответ! Почти такой же, но с двумя командами! Это способ по удобнее! Попробую! Если можно, то немного разъясните строчку develop:develop.

Comment: @EugeneTM, имена веток - откуда и куда.

Comment: @Qwertiy  из develop remote: в develop locate? правильно я понял?

Comment: @EugeneTM, дополнил ответ

Comment: @alexander barakin Спасибо! Крайне полезная информация!

Answer (score 1):

Делаете `git clone` - получаете, весь репозиторий потом создаете ветку, которая вам нужна, применяете изменения и затем `git merge`. Либо так, либо я вас не понял.

Comment: git clone не будет работать. К примеру я делаю так git checkout develop ,а гит мне говорит мол такой ветки не существует. Но она Есть!!!  В Remout репозитории. Собственно вот и вопрос, как мне её добавить в уже существующий локальный репозиторий , без пересоздания папки проекта с нужной веткой.

Comment: У всех ``git clone`` работает, а у него вдруг почему-то не будет...

Comment: @Эникейщик Я имел ввиду что не сам clone не сработает а, в моём случае. Так как он создаст такую же папку внутри уже существующей. А, мне это не нужно.

Comment: ``git clone`` нужно делать в самом начале. Тогда будут все ветки. Да и сейчас никто не мешает склонировать отдельную ветку не удаляя уже имеющейся.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже вы не совсем понимаете концепцию работы git. Вы можете иметь локально сколько угодно веток, ничего при этом не удаляя, и переключаться между ними как вам угодно. Для начала нужно сделать `git commit` всех ваших локальных изменений в эту вашу `localbranch`. Затем сделать `git checkout` ветки `develop`, потом `git pull` (чтобы забрать новые изменения в `develop` с удаленного сервера) и только после этого `git merge localbranch`.

Comment: Это не то что мне нужно! Я так и делаю сейчас. к примеру я делаю так `git clone --single-branch -b localBranch *url*` делаю функцию там, сделал. Теперь я хочу перейти в ветку develop. Но я клонировал только одну ветку и при переходе git мне выдаст что такой венки нет.

Comment: Что я делаю в таком случае. Удаляю проект клонирую develop, после делаю merge localBranch. А, мне нужно что бы не пришлось не чего удалят. А, просто нужно дозалить ветку в уже существующий репозиторий.

Comment: Вы какую-то дичь делаете. Заберите с удаленного в свой локальный репозиторий ветку orign/develop.

Comment: дичью здесь даже и не пахнет! Я вам не говорю что бы вы также делали, а если не знаете ответа то и советовать не нужно!